# Got an Error while uploading IOS App to App Store Connect. "Invalid Binary. The value of LSApplicationLaunchProhibited"

Tags: ios, xcode, watchos

Error Screenshot

[image: 1]

While distributing the companion iOS app for my watch App I am getting the following error
“Asset Validation Failed

Invalid Binary. The value of LSApplicationLaunchProhibited in Payload/iOSMealCoach.app/Info.plist can’t change after your app has been released. (ID: ***<some Id number>**)”

Below are the steps I followed

1. I had created an Apple Watch Get MealCoach app and published it on the App Store . This worked successfully
2. After that in Xcode I created a new iOS app target and developed the companion iOS app
3. The iOS App seems to work fine in the simulator.
4. But when I try to click “Product” -> “Archive” -> “Distribute App” to upload to App Store Connect I get the following error
5. Asset Validation Failed . “Invalid Binary. The value of LSApplicationLaunchProhibited in Payload/iOSMealCoach.app/Info.plist can’t change after your app has been released. (ID: ***<some Id number>**)”
6. I cannot find “LSApplicationLaunchProhibited” in Info.plist and I have not changed any value called LSApplicationLaunchProhibited

Please let me know how to fix the above error

I tried finding the field "LSApplicationLaunchProhibited" in Xcode info.plist but I could not find it

Comment: See if any of [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=LSApplicationLaunchProhibited) provides any clues for you.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. developer.apple.com/forums/thread/65948 I resolved the issue by changing my bundle identifier